# Visual Studio: eslint errors underlined in red

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, eslint

I'm using Visual Studio Community and the eslint warnings in my javascript files are shown in red. It's really confusing, makes you thing at first that you have a compile error but actually not, everything is fine.

So, my question, how can I change the underline color to green ? I guess there is a way to tell Visual Studio that those are actually warning and not error but I can't find this option anywhere.

I can't believe I couldn't find any answer on the net, I must not be the only one annoyed by that...

Edit:
Here is an example of an "error":

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As discussed on the airbnb eslint preset [github](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/853) page:

> They are errors intentionally. Warnings are mostly useless, since they
>   are easily ignored. If it's not an error, it's not enforced

This seems to be the rule of thumb for all eslint presets. You can manually set each eslint rule to warn in the .eslintrc.json file;

```
"rules": {
  "no-const-assign": "warn",
  "no-this-before-super": "warn",
}
```

That should at least turn the red lines into a bit less annoying yellow. There also seem to be several plugins available that automatically set all rules to "warn", such as [eslint-plugin-only-warn](https://github.com/bfanger/eslint-plugin-only-warn).

Comment: Mmh, I'm really surprised they are not an option for that. In VSCode it's a simple settings. Quite disappointed. I ended disabling Lint. Thanks for your reply

Comment: This is wrong. Simply make the linting issues block CI and now they cannot be ignored, and you get the best of both worlds. No need to distract the developer with 'errors' that are perfectly valid during work-in-progress changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the options menu: `Tools` > `Options`
Search for `JavaScript Errors`

Or find it under:
`Text Editor` > `JavaScript/TypeScript` > `Code Validation` > `JavaScript Errors`

Set `Show errors as warnings` to **true**

Or disable completely by setting:
`Enable JavaScript errors` to **false**

Comment: If I do that, real error are gonna be disabled no ? I still want the errors, I just don't want eslint warning to be treated as errors :/

Comment: In that case Rob's answer is more on point. I'm used to go through the warnings and keep it all very clean.